# Recover data from broken screen device when USB debugging turned off

Tags: backup, data-recovery, xiaomi, broken-screen, miui

My Redmi Note 8 phone screen is broken and I cannot control it. I need to get my photos and videos.

I try to google the problem but all answers I get need to enable debugging mode.

Is there a way to have the photos in my case?

Comment: Have you tried researching how to enable debugging mode with a broken screen? What did you find? Please [edit] your question as you find any methods that didn't work for you, as that prevents that someone will spend time suggesting that method (which doesn't work for some reason).

Comment: you can't get data off device (except you previously unlocked bootloader). check [google](https://photos.google.com) or [mi cloud](https://i.mi.com) cloud for backups. if you don't mind wasting money try to remote install this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.displaylink.desktop.demo) from PC browser (additional [hardware](https://www.displaylink.com/products/usb-adapters) required)